# NSKVODeallocate in crash log

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, key-value-observing, weak-references

A crash log that comes from a user of my app shows the crash stack as shown below. I have a hard time interpreting what is going on here, especially with the NSKVODeallocate in there. I know of the crashes where the NSKVODeallocate throws an exception, which are generally caused by a KVO observer that has not been removed before deallocation of the class.

But that is not the case here: the NSKVODeallocate calls dealloc on a CBPeripheral that eventually leads to the crash.

Does this mean that the CBPeripheral has a KVO observer on my BLE_Device class? Does it mean that the BLE_Device has a KVO observer on the CBPeripheral class? Does it have anything to do with KVO at all - I read somewhere on the web that this is how weak pointers are implemented. But BLE_Device does definitely not have a weak pointer to a CBPeripheral. It does have a strong pointer to a CBPeripheral (the `currentDevice`), but I would expect that to be deallocated from the `[BLE_Device .cxx_destruct]` directly.

Here is the stack trace:[image: Stack trace]

The BLE_Device dealloc, if it relevant:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    currentDevice.delegate = nil;
    peripheralTableView.delegate = nil;
    selector.delegate = nil;
    CM.delegate = nil;
    if (currentDevice != nil) {
        [CM cancelPeripheralConnection:currentDevice];
    }
    if (CM.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [CM stopScan];
    }
}
```